# Why is every url "redirecting" to the welcome-file url?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

**Servlets**

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class AServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

-- loads an `.jsp` and displays "AServlet"

```
@WebServlet("/b")
public class BServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

-- returns an simple JSON

**index.html**

-- displays "Not a JSP"

**web.xml**

```
...
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
...
```

Every url that doesn't match an servlet executes the same action as the A servlet.

Eg:

- ...localhost.../AppName/ -> displays *AServlet* - **ok**
- ...localhost.../AppName/**loremipsum** -> displays *AServlet* - **WHY DOESN'T IT RETURN A 404 NOT FOUND?**
- ...localhost.../AppName/**b** -> returns JSON - **ok**
- ...localhost.../AppName/**index.html** -> even if the file exists, still displays "AServlet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping a Servlet to "/" makes it the default servlet which means it will handle all requests that do not match any other mapping.